# Can implicit object application be used with EL in JSP 2.0?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

is it possible to use the implicit object '`Application`' using EL in JSP 2.0?  For example, instead of

```
<%=application.getInitParameter("appkey")%>
```

I want an EL version.  I know I can use JSTL initParam but wondering if there is a way with Application.. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${applicationScope.appKey}
```

[See here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7)